# response header VS meta tag

Tags: html, seo, http-headers

I can declare some info, like encoding and language, in meta-tag or in response-header.
My question: what the best way (maybe them both), for **SEO** and **old-browsers**?

meta-tag example:

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
```

(PHP) header example:

```
header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8');
```

What's better ?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Meta http-equiv is little more than a joke. When specifying Content-Type with it, only the `charset` section counts for anything, and then only when the real HTTP headers fail to specify the encoding.

Comment: by default the Content-Type header is "text/html". and browser (at least firefox) reads it not as utf-8. But if http-equiv Content-Type specified, it works right.

Comment: @Dani-Br — So by default PHP fails to specify the encoding in the HTTP headers, and the behaviour is as I said.

Comment: @Quentin If you are using PHP, you can always add your own header. How should PHP know the charset of the content you are generating?

Answer (score 20):

Do both. The header takes precedence, but if the HTML page is accessed locally, there are no HTTP-headers, so you want to have `<meta charset="...">` as a safety mechanism.

Comment: When page is accessed locally (when page was saved on user's PC), it's does by the encoding of the file, and browser know how save the file by meta/header info. So, my question is only about server side.

Comment: @Dani-Br This is nonsense. Determining "the encoding of the file" is precisely what the meta tag is for. OSes and file systems don't magically store an associated encoding with every text file.