# Why use meta tag "Pragma" and "Expires" in head section of html

Tags: html

Why use meta tag "Pragma" and "Expires" in head section of html like this.
Thanks.

`<META HTTP-EQUIV="Pragma" CONTENT="no-cache">` 
`<META HTTP-EQUIV="Expires" CONTENT="-1">`

Answer (score 19, accepted):

[Using this will disable the browser to cache your webpage.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1341089/using-meta-tags-to-turn-off-caching-in-all-browsers)

Disabling cache has some valuable advantages.

Like when you update your files on the server, if happened that the browser doesnt have a cached copy of your webpage then it would force itself to load the updated content of your website.

One of the disadvantage of this is the impact on page downloading. Since you dont have cached copy on your browser, it will always download all of your assets from the server thus affecting time and also consuming bandwidth.

Try reading this [article](http://www.technicallymotivated.com/2011/04/tutorial-browser-cache/#.Uv9hJvmSyg4).

Comment: OK, And any disadvantage?

Comment: [These responses](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9417024/response-header-vs-meta-tag) disagree, calling the meta tag "little more than a joke" ...

Comment: @Matt why do you say responses (multiple)? I see only one. And the question is general and very unclear. This question is more specific.

Comment: Using those tags will do nothing in HTML 5

Answer (score 12):

Both tags are meant to prevent browsers from caching the HTML page, and they usually do that. This means that access to the page may be slower especially if it is frequently visited. Probably most commonly, these tags are inserted by people who do not understand how caches work. See [Caching Tutorial for Web Authors and Webmasters](http://www.mnot.net/cache_docs/).

There are several ways to try to prevent caching. These specific tags have no official definition, and they do not conform to HTML5 CR.