# Which takes precedence, http-equiv or HTTP response header?

Tags: html, http

This question seems duplicate, but after some research, no solid answer is found. The sub questions are:

1. When `http-equiv` and HTTP response header have the same key, and their corresponding value conflict, which one takes precedence?
2. Is there any specification for the 1st question, even if it's not followed by browsers?
3. If there is no specification, what happens? Was there any discussion in standard groups? This behaviour definitely need to be defined in some standards.

Here are some research work:

- I checked [4.2.5.3 Pragma directives](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/document-metadata.html#attr-meta-http-equiv) in HTML specification, but precedence is not mentioned (except for `http-equiv="set-cookie"`, in which case real HTTP response header takes precedence).
- In [response header VS meta tag](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9417024/response-header-vs-meta-tag), it seems real HTTP response header takes precedence for `Content-Type`
- In [Which X-UA-Compatible takes precedence? Http-header or Meta-tags?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9128739/which-x-ua-compatible-takes-precedence-http-header-or-meta-tags), it seems `http-equiv` takes precedence for `X-UA-Compatible`

In my opinion, either decision makes sense, but isn't there a general answer?

Comment: Note: the `set-cookie` directive is stated to be non-conforming and should be avoided... I didn't notice anything about precedence. It seems to me that the assumption is that the browsers parse HTML after receiving the HTTP response and the `content-type` header... hence (with the exception of transport headers such as `Content-Type` and `Content-Length`, that were already consumed before parsing the HTML), new data in the `meta` tags will overwrite older data inherited from the HTTP response.

Comment: @Myst, for `Content-Type` or `Content-Length`, it's easy to understand that HTTP response header should take precedence. But for other headers, it's confusing. If think from timeline point of view, `http-equiv` is consumed after HTTP header and should take precedence. However, if `http-equiv` is taken as imitation of HTTP header, then the "real" HTTP header should take precedence...

Comment: The way I read section 4.2.5.3: "the user agent **must**"... I believe it's meant to covey that the browser is required to process the new data. Point number 3 to your question also demonstrates that this is the implemented interpretation.

Answer (score 2):

From the documentation it is not clear what is the precedence of Content-Security-Policy in http-equiv vs. http header.
I have tested experimentaly on Firefox 62.0:

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="script-src 'self' https://www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js"/>
<script src="https://www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js"></script>
<script src="https://connect.facebook.net/en_US/fbevents.js"></script>
```

When HTTP header is not set, the console argues about facebook.net only.

With `header set Content-Security-Policy "script-src 'self' https://connect.facebook.net/en_US/fbevents.js"`
 the console argues about both www.google-analytics.com and  facebook.net.

When http-equiv is removed and header for facebook.net kept, the console correctly argues about
google-analytics.

From that it seems the combination of http-equiv and http header is detected as duplicate definition and not recognized at all.

Comment: content-security-policy was my actual question. I just learned from https://csper.io/blog/multiple-policies that when there are multiple policies (ie http-equiv and header) they are **both** enforced, so the resource will be blocked if it doesn't pass both.

Comment: @dosmanak and @mike-lippert neither both of the headers are dismissed nor are they both enforced. Mike, you misunderstood the line in the CSPer blog that says `both the policies are enforced`. The correct behavior is only the HTTP header enforced.

Extra: If you set multiple HTTP headers for CSP, then only the first header is enforced.

Comment: @RafidMuhyminWafi that wasn't my experience, but perhaps that was because of the multiple places the CSP was being set, in code and in the http-equiv header. I found if I wanted to add to the CSP I had to change both occurrences. Once that worked I didn't investigate further.

Comment: The implementation may be different across browsers. What browser do you use @MikeLippert?

Comment: @RafidMuhyminWafi, I personally almost always use firefox, so I'm just about certain that's what I was testing with. I wish there was a standard, then at least one could report a bug for one of the browsers

Comment: @RafidMuhyminWafi does that mean you have recreated my scenario with different browsers or versions with different outcomes than mine? If so, can you put your outcomes as separate answer?

Answer (score 1):

The answer posted by Shahafo may be correct for the X-UA-Compatible header and IE 11, but does not appear to be true in the general case. For example, for Firefox and Chrome, caching-related HTTP headers have a higher precedence than caching-related http-equiv tags. For IE 11, the situation is reversed.

Answer (score 0):

from [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff955275(v=vs.85).aspx):

> If both of these instructions are sent, the developer's preference
>   (meta element) takes precedence over the web server setting (HTTP
>   header).

I couldn't find whether it is IE\IIS specific behavior, or a standard.

Comment: Thanks @user3214387. As this statement is from MSDN, I take it as Microsoft technology specific.

Comment: @shahafo it's not standard behavior. I couldn't verify this on Chrome. If both headers are set on Chrome, then only the HTTP header is respected.